# Gmail popout window size

Tags: gmail

The compose popout window and the "In new window" popout for received mail are too small and in the wrong place for me. I would like them bigger. I was expecting the app to remember the last size and position, but that may not be possible for a web app.

Is there a way to change the defaults? I don't want to resize and move everytime I open a popout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following procedure will lead to the wanted result:

1. Add this URL into the browser: https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1
2. Press enter to activate the link
3. Drag the URL into the bookmark bar
   [image]
4. Close the compose window like this:
   [image]
5. If you press the newly created short cut, a maximized compose window will appear (in the same window your in and with the active Gmail login. Best would be to press the scroll wheel, creating a new tab).

All guidelines are based on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Press this button in the compose modus:
[image]

and a seperate window will be created.

Then all you have to do is maximize:
[image]

Comment: I've added a clarification to the question.  I'm hoping for a permanent solution, so that every time I open a popout it goes to the last location and size.  I have two screens, and I want it to open larger (not maximized) to the other screen.